# Is this a Box Tree Moth?

Tags: species-identification

This moth has been hanging about near my house recently (South London area, October 2021) - I have seen it 2/3 times in the last fortnight. I have never seen anything this colour before which is why it caught my eye.

Its wingspan is about 30mm and this photo was taken from the inside of a window it had landed on.

[image: potential box tree moth]

Basic google searches [lead me to believe it is a Box Tree Moth](https://butterfly-conservation.org/moths/box-tree-moth) - am I correct?

Comment: What a beauty, do you have a picture of the back?

Comment: @CoDa Unfortunately not, it flew off before I could get one